# Get coordinates from homography

Tags: python, opencv

```
H, s = cv2.findHomography(matchedPointsCurrent, matchedPointsPrev, cv2.RANSAC, 4)
```

How i can find new coordinates from matrix homography?

Comment: Question should be more clear imo, but it seems like you are looking for `warpPerspective`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the homography matrix (`retval`) from the [findHomography()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) you should use [warpPerspective()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) to get the new image.

So, get the matrix:

```
h_mat, _ = cv2.findHomography(src_point, dst_points)
```

Get the new image from original image:

```
warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(src_img, h_mat, dsize)
```

Where `dsize` is `(width, height)` of the warped_image

Comment: 'Where dsize is (width, height) of the warped_image'- maybe dsize is (width, height) of the src_img?